# In qml,could connect signal & slot as QueuedConnection with connect() method of signal object?

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

As the title.
I have a signal that defined in c++.
In qml, I want to connect the signal to a fuction with queued connection.

```
onCppObjectChanged{
    cppObject.signal1.connect(onSignal1)//How can I set the connection type.
}
fuction onSignal1{...}
```

Comment: Isn't the connect always queued from c++ to QML or at least `AutoConnection`which does a queued connection when sender and receiver are on different threads!?

Comment: I knew it on different threads.But I thought that the connection is DirectConnection in my case(on same thread).